# How to Endow Azure App Service Web Site with Appropriate (Minimal) Azure SQL Database Privileges?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

**Goal:**

Assign appropriate Azure SQL database privileges to App Service Web Site's system service principal (or better yet) the user assigned service principal.

**Background:**

After having followed along with [Alexandre's tutorial on creating Azure SQL administrators](https://www.techwatching.dev/posts/sqlclient-active-directory-authent) I created a simple Blazor Server App that can insert entries into a simple Azure SQL resident table because the system assigned service principal of the Azure App Service Web site is an administrator for the Azure SQL database.

**Problem:**

Database administrator privileges are not appropriate or necessary for the Azure App Service Web site. I need to endow the Azure App Service Web site with minimal privileges (such as db_datawriter) to be consistent with Microsoft's recommend best practices.

**What is Working (Updated):**

I've been [following along with Jesse's tutorial](https://sqlitybi.com/how-to-create-azure-ad-users-on-azure-sql-database/) where he endows his account as the Azure SQL administrator and creates new accounts with limited roles like db_datareader and dt_datawriter and db_ddladmin. This was not working previously (when I first posted).

**Tue May 24 2022 Update:**

I started over again (with a new azure SQL database) following Jesse's tutorial and I can now

1. log into the Query Explorer
2. create a user
3. grant access to that user to update, select and insert into a table
4. Connect with SSMS with no password and access the database tables as that user
5. Run my blazor app and insert into the table as well (with no password!)

**New Questions (Tue May 24 2022):**

When I deploy my blazor app to Azure AppService Web app, it cannot connect.

1. How do I write bicep code to grant my azure app service resident blazor app access to my azure SQL database? I think I need to use the system assigned service principal for the web app (does this have a password?) and use SQLCMD.EXE to execute those CREATE USER and ALTER ROLE commands. How do I do that? The problem is that the system assigned service principal of the web app is not an active directory object. Conversely, "az ad user show" does not have a principalId I can use as a user assigned service principal that I could assign to the web app.

So when I am running on my desktop dev machine, DefaultAzureCredential is detecting that I am logged to Azure with the Microsoft account and I can debug my blazor app on my dev machine...

2. How do I configure Azure SQL to allow access from the Azure App Service web app as well as access from my desktop dev machine? This is easy to do with cosmos SQL and I'm thinking it should be possible with Azure SQL as well.

Thanks

Siegfried

Comment: use managed identity. To create and set permissions for external provider user, you have to login into AAD Account.

Comment: I granted my AAD account globaladmin owner access to the Azure SQL database server, logged in as globaladmin  and tried to go to the query editor. I got the same error: Login failed for user '<token-identified-principal>'

Answer (score -1):

This article I recently published should be able to help you: https://dev.to/azure/create-and-connect-to-an-azure-sql-db-9k0. And yes, this sentences you mentioned "it looks like this is the way to conform to the Microsoft recommend Best Practices of abandoning passwords in favor of service principals and managed identities", is definitely correct.

Comment: Don't post link-only answers. Instead, post the relevant details contained in the link.

Comment: I love your article because you don't use the GUI. However, the article ends with a connection string that requires a password and that is what we both agreed should be avoided! Can you write a follow-on article very quickly?